# What are the basis elements of an algbera called?

Tags: abstract-algebra

A quaternion is defined as $a+ib+jc+kd$.

This can be thought of as a dot product of the real vector $(a,b,c,d)$ with the elements $(1,i,j,k)$.

Is there a name for these elements. e.g. what are $i$, $j$ and $k$ ?

They are unit vectors in some sense. But they also have a multiplication rule. e.g. $ij=k$, $ji=-k$.

But also they are not members of a group. (The quaternion group has 8 members $1,-1,i,-i,j,-j,k,-k$.) They are sort of like half a group.

Would they be called something like "basis algbraic elements" or "complex units" something? I can't seem to find any name for them!

Comment: I'm not aware of a name for a basis of an algebra. One issue is that there's rarely a privileged choice of basis.

Comment: It seems hasty to use such a special example to motivate general terminology.

Comment: @Lee well it's not really a special example. One could use octonions, or clifford algebras. Or even group-alegberas except that is easier as the elements are members of a group so could just be called group-elements. For Clifford algebras they seem to just referred to as basis elements.

Answer (score 2):

I think they are still called basis elements since algebra preserves the properties of a vector space: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebra_over_a_field#Structure_coefficients

Comment: "Basis elements" is not a bad name for them I guess. As in "the multiplication rules for the basis elements of the algebra are..." I guess the answer was in my question!